# Problems installing gems with RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Debian 5
Ruby version 1.8.7
Rubygems version 2.0.3
Rails version 3.2.12

I made my Ruby on Rails app and want to deploy it publicly, so I tried to install "Mongrel" without any luck and then "Unicorn" also without any luck and same error.

```
vps1198019:~# gem install mongrel
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mongrel:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/ext/http11/gem_make.out
```

and

```
vps1198019:~# gem install unicorn
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing unicorn:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kgio-2.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kgio-2.8.0/ext/kgio/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Debian, but do you have the development tools installed?  It needs to compile the native extensions for the gems.

Comment: I believe yes: "build-essential"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for my problem by installed it more manually. I downloaded Unicorn from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1306 (.gem file). Stored it in server. Went to that folder with terminal. Then I accessed it with

```
gem install --local unicorn.gem
```

Then it prompted that I must have kgio and raindrops so I installed them:

```
gem install kgio
gem install raindrops
```

and repeated first command.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below command. Because of version mismatch, gem is not installed.

```
$ gem install mongrel --pre
```

Comment: The same error persisted even with an earlier versions of mongrel.